# Unable to test on iOS 5 simulator even though it is installed

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator

I was able to install iOS 5.0 and 5.1 in Xcode 4.5, and on the Simulator > Hardware menu I can switch between the different versions. However, on Xcode I only see iOS6. So even if the Simulator was set to iOS5, when I click on Run in Xcode, the app would run in iOS6 on the Simulator. How can I run the app in iOS5 simulator?

here is the image

[image]

Comment: Is iOS5 a valid target for your app?

Comment: Have you check by setting deployment target to 5.0?

Comment: @Ankur S is right -- a deployment target higher than 5.x will preclude that option in xcode.

Comment: I switched the deployment target to iOS5 on the project but the Run button in Xcode only shows 6 still.

Comment: You might also need to do it for the target.

Comment: in the target is important to do it

Comment: Sorry where exactly do I set this? While in the project, I changed it to iOS5 on the right hand side, under Interface Builder Document - Document Versioning - Deployment drop-down menu.

Comment: Never mind found it by double-clicking on the project :)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your project is set to support iOS 5/5.1 as a deployment target:

[image]